# What the most efficient way to make a three tables JOIN with a WHERE clause in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, junction-table

I'm working with postgreSQL 9.3.

I'd like to say that my question is a bit subjective but I didn't find any related questions or articles...

I have three tables as following:

artists:

```
+--------+----------+
|artistId|   name   |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | James    |
| 2      | Jack     |
| 3      | Henry    |
| 4      | Tom      |
+--------+----------+
```

genres:

```
+---------+-----------+
| genreId |    name   |
+---------+-----------+
|   1     |   rock    |
|   2     |   dub     |
+---------+-----------+
```

and the junction table artistsGenres:

```
+--------+---------+
|artistId| genreId |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |     1   |
|      2 |     2   |
|      3 |     1   |
|      4 |     2   |
+--------+---------+
```

I want to get all the artists by genre name.
For the moment I do it like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM artistsGenres aG
  INNER JOIN artists a ON a.artistId = aG.artistId
WHERE aG.genreId = (SELECT genreId FROM genres WHERE name = 'dub');
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Looks like your query is incorrect, you are matching aG.artitsId against genres.genreId.

Comment: You're right, I edited my question.

Comment: Can an artist have more than one genre? (for instance, could a artistsgenres row exist with {artistId=1, genreId=2} ?)

Comment: @wildplasser , yes it can have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is better not to use a subquery if it can be done with a join. However with a bit of luck the query planner rewrites subquery as a join for you! Here is how it would look if you did it yourself.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM artistsGenres aG
  INNER JOIN artists a ON a.artistId = aG.artistId
  INNER JOIN genres g ON g.genreId=aG.genreId
WHERE g.name='dub'
```

In which order you do the joins doesn't matter much as postgresql will reorder them to what it thinks works best.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM artists a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM artistsGenres aG
  JOIN genres g ON g.genreId = aG.genreId
  WHERE aG.artistId = a.artistId 
  AND g.name = 'dub'
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your query seems to be a little bit slower than the query of Eelke (but my test table is very small, it's maybe the reason).

Comment: For non-trivial cases, it can only be faster. Do note that the queries will produce different results: in the case of more-than-one genre per artist (this would also need the selection to allow multiple choices, like in `AND g.name IN( 'country',  'dub')` , @Eelke's query will yield multiple result rows per artist, mine one (or zero) rows per artist.

Comment: Consider adding a couple of lines of explanation in brief as to why this is the best(and under what circumstances). Links to good references will help as well.

Comment: @wildplasser: how could Eelke's query yield multiple result rows per artist (since one artist can have several genres but can't have several times the same genre) ?